# Generate a random mac address

Tags: c#, networking

I am looking for a method in C# which generates a random MAC number. Google is pretty thin on that one.

Thx a lot

**SOLUTION:**

With the help of Yahia I was able to code the following solution. Thx again!

```
public static string GenerateMACAddress()
    {
        var sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        var r = new Random();
        int number;
        byte b;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            number = r.Next(0, 255);
            b = Convert.ToByte(number);
            if (i == 0)
            {
                b = setBit(b, 6); //--> set locally administered
                b = unsetBit(b, 7); // --> set unicast 
            }
            sBuilder.Append(number.ToString("X2"));
        }
        return sBuilder.ToString().ToUpper();
    }

    private static byte setBit(byte b, int BitNumber)
    {
        if (BitNumber < 8 && BitNumber > -1)
        {
            return (byte)(b | (byte)(0x01 << BitNumber));
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
            "Der Wert für BitNumber " + BitNumber.ToString() + " war nicht im zulässigen Bereich! (BitNumber = (min)0 - (max)7)");
        }
    }

    private static byte unsetBit(byte b, int BitNumber)
    {
        if (BitNumber < 8 && BitNumber > -1)
        {
            return (byte)(b | (byte)(0x00 << BitNumber));
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
            "Der Wert für BitNumber " + BitNumber.ToString() + " war nicht im zulässigen Bereich! (BitNumber = (min)0 - (max)7)");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You only need that bit twiddling on the leftmost byte, not all of them. And you don't need to write methods to set and clear bits: use the | and & operators.

Comment: I am confused. Why are you setting the upper bits of the first byte? I thought the unicast\multicast bit is the lowest bit of the first byte and the globally-unique\locally-administered is the second lowest bit of the first byte. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address

Comment: This method seems to generate invalid mac addresses still

Comment: It code inccorect. You are working in a if with a variable b, but  in code sBuilder.Append(number.ToString("X2")); You working with variable number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such method in the .NET framework...

You will need to write one yourself - read the [format description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address), use a [random generator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) to get 6 random numbers between 0 and 255, setup the 2 relevant bits (for globally unique/locally administered) as need be and then [transform the number to hex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#XFormatString) (i.e. `X2`, 2 digits per number, left padded with 0) and [join these together with `:` as delimiter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx)...

Comment: thx so far this is exactly what I am looking to achieve here. I will give it a try

Comment: @MUG4N you are welcome :-) I added some MSDN links for relevant methods etc. HTH

Answer (score 12):

A slightly less verbose solution (which I think still achieves the same outcome):

```
public static string GetRandomMacAddress()
{
    var random = new Random();
    var buffer = new byte[6];
    random.NextBytes(buffer);
    var result = String.Concat(buffer.Select(x => string.Format("{0}:", x.ToString("X2"))).ToArray());
    return result.TrimEnd(':');
}
```

This gives a  formatted MAC, remove string.Format and Trim if unformatted is required

Comment: The string formatting ToString->Format->Concat->TrimEnd can be replaced with a simplified ToString->Join

Answer (score 2):

MUG4N's solution has a problem. You have to tweak the LEAST significant two bits not the MOST significant two.

So instead of

```
b = setBit(b, 6); //--> set locally administered
b = unsetBit(b, 7); // --> set unicast
```

it should be

```
b = setBit(b, 1); //--> set locally administered
b = unsetBit(b, 0); // --> set unicast
```

Also the `unsetBit()` is incorrect. The relevant line should be

```
return unchecked((byte)(b & (byte)~(0x01 << BitNumber)));
```

Of course it would probably be simpler to change it to this:

```
if (i == 0)
{
    b = (byte)((b & 0xFE) | 0x02) //-->set locally administered and unicast
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Small update for those of you who have a problem generating a new MAC address for your Wifi-adapter. You just have to set the first octet of MAC address to "02", instead on what normally is "00". Setting first octet "02" actually sets the b2 bit indicating that the MAC address is locally administered.

[image]

You can read more about it here:
http://blog.technitium.com/2011/05/tmac-issue-with-wireless-network.html

Code:

```
public static string GetRandomWifiMacAddress()
{
    var random = new Random();
    var buffer = new byte[6];
    random.NextBytes(buffer);
    buffer[0] = 02;
    var result = string.Concat(buffer.Select(x => string.Format("{0}", x.ToString("X2"))).ToArray());
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a helper class to generate random mac.

```
public static class MacAddress
{
    private static readonly Random Random = new Random();

    public static string GetSignatureRandomMac(string generic = "AA")
    {
        string[] macBytes = new[]
        {
            generic,
            generic,
            generic,
            Random.Next(1, 256).ToString("X"),
            Random.Next(1, 256).ToString("X"),
            Random.Next(1, 256).ToString("X")
        };

        return string.Join("-", macBytes);
    }

    public static string GetRandomMac()
    {
        string[] macBytes = new[]
        {
            Random.Next(1, 256).ToString("X"),
            Random.Next(1, 256).ToString("X"),
            Random.Next(1, 256).ToString("X"),
            Random.Next(1, 256).ToString("X"),
            Random.Next(1, 256).ToString("X"),
            Random.Next(1, 256).ToString("X")
        };

        return string.Join("-", macBytes);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Console.WriteLine(MacAddress.GetRandomMac());
Console.WriteLine(MacAddress.GetSignatureRandomMac());
Console.WriteLine(MacAddress.GetSignatureRandomMac("BB"));
```

Comment: Use ".ToString("X2")" instead of ".ToString("X")" or else you will get some single values sometime resulting in a MAC address with less than 12 characters.

Answer (score 1):

we can generate a random number and we can modify only last 2 bit of the first byte  using bitwise operators:

```
    public string GetRandomWifiMacAddress()
    {
        var random = new Random();
        var buffer = new byte[6];
        random.NextBytes(buffer);
        buffer[0] &= 0b11111110;
        buffer[0] |= 0b00000010;
        var result = string.Concat(buffer.Select(x => string.Format("{0}", x.ToString("X2"))).ToArray());
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

There isn't a function within .NET to generate MAC addresses. It would have to be written.

MAC Addresses are generally meant to be unique and set by the OEM of the NIC. Different manufacturing have a certain allocated prefix. A sample list can be found here; https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob_plain;f=manuf

Off the top of my head, I don't know of any libraries that exist to generate MAC addresses (as it's not a common requirement), however it wouldn't be too difficult to create one as an address is simply 6 hexadecimal values from 00 to FF separated by a colon.