# Convert Mac Address Generation from SQL to C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I am converting an app from using stored procedures to using Entity Framework 6. I ran across a stored procedure that is generating the next Mac Address in a sequence.

Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT 
    @macAddress = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR(8), CONVERT(VARBINARY(3), 1234567), 1) + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR(8), CONVERT(VARBINARY(3), @nextMacAddressValue), 1), 3, 6), 3, 12)
```

`@nextMacAddressValue` is just an incrementing number, let's say it's 21 for this example.

I am looking for help in converting this over to C#

Comment: Can you give example of input and desired output?

Comment: The output would be "12D687000015" when @nextMacAddressValue is equal to 21

Comment: Hire someone to do that for you. If you need some job to be done - you pay for it. That's how it works.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely. `SQL` is the ANSI/ISO standard query language - but each vendor have their own "extensions" that could be useful to use - **if** we knew which vendor's database you're using ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be random.  It needs to start with the first six values and then increment sequence after that.  This did the trick.

```
var macAddress = String.Concat(1234567.ToString("X").PadLeft(6, '0'), int.Parse(nextMacAddressParameter.Value).ToString("X").PadLeft(6, '0'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The key here is maybe to not focus on how they did it exactly

If you just want a random Mac address, you can apply the solution in

[Generate a random mac address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10161291/1045881)